# Is there an alternative to a for-if loop in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I've got two Worksheets in Excel. I've written the following code to copy some data from *Worksheet 1* to *Worksheet 2*, based on some values that the user inserts in *Worksheet 2*.

The macro works fine, and does what I need it to do, but after writing it down I've come to realize two things:

1. It takes quite some time for a small set of records(260 or so), as it goes one row at a time.
2. I read that using **.select** is not good practice, and I modified the code so that I would not use it, but I'm left wondering if I could improve the code to work faster if I did use it.

So, my main questions are:

1. How can I improve the speed of the code, so that it will be able to read copy rows faster.
2. Would it be better in this case to use **.select** in my case, so that it would work faster.

My code is the following:

```
Private Sub FillUp()
Dim DateVal, EquivalentDate As Date
Dim CrncyVal
Dim CountrVal
Dim DataRng As Range
Dim endrow As Long, startrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
'Selecting the worksheets
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

''''declaring date, country and currency variables''''
DateVal = ws2.Range("E3").Value
CountryVal = UCase(ws2.Range("H3").Value)
CurrencyVal = UCase(ws2.Range("H4").Value)
EquivalentDateVal = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, DateVal)
'declaring other useful variables
startrow = 3
pasterow = 6
endrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'delete the range we will be working with
ws2.Range("A6:F265").Clear

'start the ifs, to see what info the user wants to get
If ws2.Range("E3").Value = "" Then
    'If the country cell is empty, we do nothing. We need at least this info
    MsgBox prompt:="You didn't choose a month!!", Title:="Error: Please Choose a Month"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf ws2.Range("H3").Value = "" Then
    For i = 3 To endrow
        If ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value <> "TOT" Then

            With ws1
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 5))
            End With

            Rng.Copy
            ws2.Cells(pasterow, 1).PasteSpecial
            ws2.Cells(pasterow, 6) = DateVal

            pasterow = pasterow + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Exit Sub

ElseIf ws2.Range("H4").Value = "" Then            
    For i = 3 To endrow
        If ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value <> "TOT" Then
            If ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value = CountryVal Then

                With ws1
                    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 5))
                End With

                Rng.Copy
                ws2.Cells(pasterow, 1).PasteSpecial
                ws2.Cells(pasterow, 6) = DateVal

                pasterow = pasterow + 1 
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Exit Sub
Else
    For i = 3 To endrow
        If ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value <> "TOT" Then
            If ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value = CountryVal Then
                If ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value = CurrencyVal Then

                    With ws1
                        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 5))
                    End With

                    Rng.Copy
                    ws2.Cells(pasterow, 1).PasteSpecial
                    ws2.Cells(pasterow, 6) = DateVal

                    pasterow = pasterow + 1
                End If
            End If            
        End If
    Next i
    Exit Sub

End If
End Sub
```

Any help or opinion on how I can get the code to be faster or better in any way is welcome, as I am quite new to the whole Excel/VBA world.

Thanks!!

Comment: As this is working code without any obvious problems, this question is better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `.Select` and `.Activate` is never a good practice untill you want it to be visible to user after the macro end. Here, you may use `AutoFilter` to get the thing done.

Comment: @Plutian: Not anymore actually. See [THIS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390803/is-this-question-on-topic-for-code-review)

Comment: Alex You can use autofilter as @DhirendraKumar suggested. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s/11633207#11633207) is one example

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for pointing that out, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Always found that a grey area myself but seems there actually is a firm line. Thanks for posting link.

Comment: the relevant points seem to be about narrowing the question for SO. For example, narrowing down to where bottlenecks occur.

Comment: Thanks both to @DhirendraKumar for giving the `AutoFilter` idea, and @SiddharthRout for providing an example. I will get back to the post when I manage to use it accordingly.

Comment: You might find it easier to use `Range.Find` and `Range.FindNext` methods to cycle through your data - just a thought..

Comment: @DhirendraKumar Thanks for your idea of using `Autofilter` to make the code faster! I've managed to get a working function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time and using DhirendraKumar 's idea to use `Autofilter` I've managed to get the code to work much faster. Thanks again!!

I'm answering the question so that anyone that might come searching for an answer can see this example and maybe apply it to their problem.

Answers

1. I've answered my first question with the code below. The speed has been improved by using `Autofilter`, it works faster because it doesn't go row by row.
2. I didn't use `Select` in my code, and I don't use `Activate` anymore, so I guess I did not need to use neither.

   ```
   Sub FillUp()
   Dim DateVal
   Dim CountryVal
   Dim CurrencyVal
   Dim endrow As Long, lastrow As Long, pasterow As Long
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet

   'Selecting the worksheets
   Set ws1 = Worksheets("Cost Evolution 2")
   Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

   ''''declaring date, country and currency variables''''
   DateVal = ws2.Range("E3").Value
   CountryVal = UCase(ws2.Range("H3").Value)
   CurrencyVal = UCase(ws2.Range("H4").Value)

   'declaring other useful variables
   pasterow = 6
   lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   'delete the range we will be working with
   ws2.Range("A6:F265").Clear

   'start the ifs, to see what info the user wants to get
   If DateVal = "" Then
       'If the country cell is empty, we do nothing. We need at least this info
       MsgBox prompt:="You didn't choose a month!!", Title:="Error: Please Choose a Month"
       Exit Sub
   ElseIf CountryVal = "" Then
       With ws1.Range("A2:E2")
           .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>TOT"
       End With

       ' make sure results were returned from the filter
       If (ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Address <> "$A$1") Then

           ws1.Range("A3:E" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & CStr(pasterow))

           endrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

           ws2.Range("F" & pasterow & ":F" & endrow).Formula = DateVal

           pasterow = endrow + 1
       End If

       ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
       MsgBox prompt:="Inserted complete month"
       Exit Sub

   ElseIf CurrencyVal = "" Then
       With ws1.Range("A2:E2")
           .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>TOT"
           .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=CountryVal
       End With

       ' make sure results were returned from the filter
       If (ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Address <> "$A$1") Then

           ws1.Range("A3:E" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & CStr(pasterow))

           endrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

           ws2.Range("F" & pasterow & ":F" & endrow).Formula = DateVal

           pasterow = endrow + 1
       End If

       ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
       MsgBox prompt:="Inserted complete month for the chosen country"
       Exit Sub
   Else
       With ws1.Range("A2:E2")
           .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=CountryVal
           .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=CurrencyVal
           .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>TOT"
       End With

       ' make sure results were returned from the filter
       If (ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Address <> "$A$1") Then

           ws1.Range("A3:E" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & CStr(pasterow))

           endrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

           ws2.Range("F" & pasterow & ":F" & endrow).Formula = DateVal

           pasterow = endrow + 1
       End If

       ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
       MsgBox prompt:="Inserted complete month for the chosen country and currency"
       Exit Sub

   End If
   End Sub
   ```